# Studying the behavior of a two variable function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Consider the function
$$
f(X,Y)= \frac{Y*X}{2\sqrt{(3+X^2/2)(4+Y^2/2) }}
$$

Is it correct to say that the higher $X,Y$ in absolute value, the higher $f(X,Y)$ in absolute value? If not, how does $f(X,Y)$ vary with $X,Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the expressions a little, let $$r = 2\sqrt{(3 + x^2/2)(4 + y^2/2)} = \sqrt{(6 + x^2)(8 + y^2)}$$

Then it follows that

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{6y(8+y^2)}{r^3}$$ and $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = \frac{8x(6+x^2)}{r^3}$$

So if $y < 0$, then $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} < 0$, which means that $F$ decreases as $x$ increases, and if $y > 0$ then $F$ increases with $x$. Similarly if $x < 0$ then $F$ decreases when $y$ increases, and if $x > 0$, then $F$ increases with $y$.

Breaking it down into the 4 quadrants:

- If $x < 0, y < 0$, then as the |x|, |y| increases, that means that $x, y$ are decreasing, so $F$ will be increasing, and since $F$ is positive in this region, $|F|$ increases.
- If $x > 0, y > 0$, then $x, y$ increase with $|x|, |y|$, and so $F$ increases, and is positive, so $|F|$ increases.
- If $x > 0, y < 0$, then $x$ increases with $|x|$ and $y$ decreases as $|y|$ increases. Therefore $F$ decreases as either of $|x|,|y|$ increases, but as $F < 0$ in this region, this means $|F|$ increases.
- If $x < 0, y > 0$, then $x$ decreases as $|x|$ increases and $y$ increases withe $|y|$. Therefore $F$ again decreases as either of $|x|,|y|$ increases, but $F < 0$, so $|F|$ increases.

So you are correct, $|F|$ increases with either of $|x|,|y|$. Note, though, that if $x = 0$ or $y = 0$, then $F = 0$, so its value doesn't change with the other variable. I.e., $|F|$ is not strictly increasing with $|x|, |y|$, unless both quantities are non-zero.